# Why delegates cannot be passed always as the same way as functions

Tags: c#, delegates

Why can't delegates be passed as normal functions (sometimes).
For example:

```
public delegate int CompareBy(Rectangle first);
```

And the following code won't work,

```
list.OrderBy(compare);
```

Where `compare` is passed as an argument and is of type `CompareBy`. But this,

```
list.OrderBy(x => compare(x));
```

Will work.
I know that there are a lot of posts about which are similar to this, but I cannot find such an example.

Comment: `x => compare(x)` will also be converted to a delegate type. Are you asking why overload resolution doesn't work for this method group conversion?

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.OrderBy` takes an argument of type `Func<TSource, TKey>`. `CompareBy` is a different type, there is no implicit conversion between `CompareBy` and `Func<Rectangle, int>`.

`x => compare(x)` creates a new `Func<Rectangle, int>` instance bound to an anonymous function, which does nothing but invoke the `CompareBy` delegate.

An alternative way of getting rid of the error is

```
list.OrderBy(compare.Invoke)
```

since this is able to construct a new `Func<Rectangle, int>` instance without the help of any anonymous function, or more explicitly,

```
list.OrderBy(new Func<Rectangle, int>(compare.Invoke))
```

since this is what the use `compare.Invoke` will actually resolve to anyway, or

```
list.OrderBy(new Func<Rectangle, int>(compare))
```

which is yet another syntax to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I don't understand, why `there is no implicit conversion between CompareBy and Func<Rectangle, int>` ? `compare` is a concrete implementation that takes `Recatangle` as an argument and returns `int`. Sorry, if the question is stupid, but I am new in C# and I am not in depth in such kind of stuff.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DPM It's the same reason why there's no implicit conversion between `class A { public int i; }` and `class B { public int i; }`: the runtime cannot rule out that the type information itself might be relevant too in some way, even though in your case it isn't. The programmer (you?) opted not to use the same delegate type for whatever reason, and the runtime is not second-guessing the programmer's intentions. The programmer could choose to use only `Func<Rectangle, int>` and remove the `CompareBy` delegate, avoiding this problem entirely.